# MySQL Today and Month To Date query

Tags: mysql

I have a simple sales table which contains the following columns and data

TABLE NAME: **SALES**

```
SALES_ID SALES_DATE SALES_PERSON SALES_TOTAL
       1 2019-01-02 Jones          5236.6
       2 2019-01-17 Jones          3324.26
       3 2019-01-03 Jim            2257.25
       4 2019-01-17 Jim            5232.21
       5 2019-01-13 Josh          3254.2
       6 2019-01-15 Josh           215.36
```

Now my question is, assuming today date is 2019-01-17, how to get below result using a single query string?

```
`SALES_PERSON`, `TODAY_SALES`, `MONTH_TO_DATE_SALES`
Jones           3324.26        8560.86
Jim             5232.21        7489.46
Josh            0.00           3469.56
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That depends on the logic behind that result - can you explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Sub query to get this result

```
select SALES_PERSON,      
IFNULL(( select SUM(SALES_TOTAL) from SALES where SALES_DATE = '2019-01-17' and SALES_PERSON = sal.SALES_PERSON  ),0) as TODAY_SALES,
IFNULL(( select SUM(SALES_TOTAL) from SALES where MONTH(SALES_DATE)='01' and SALES_PERSON = sal.SALES_PERSON  ),0) as MONTH_TO_DATE_SALES 
from SALES as sal

group by SALES_PERSON
```

Comment: Tried your query string but it returns no record. I try adding 'group by' but to no avail.

Comment: @comudus Are you facing any mysql error?

Comment: Please try with updated query

Comment: I got no error using your first query. It only shows total for Month To Date column. Other columns are empty. Will try your updated query later and let you know if it's work

Comment: @comudus Okay fine

Comment: your latest query returns result, showing Jones and Jim Today Sales and Month To Date sales. However, Josh sales is not showing because no sales for today. I need to show his Month to Date data as well. many thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @comudus try this updated query

Comment: Thank you so much @Siva. I modified your code a bit by replacing the NULL value with 0 and that's the last thing I need. Your helps are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I modified @Siva query string and this is the final query that satisfy my question. Thanks a lot!

```
SELECT
    SALES_PERSON,
    IFNULL( ( SELECT SUM( SALES_TOTAL ) FROM SALES WHERE SALES_DATE = '2019-01-17' AND SALES_PERSON = sal.SALES_PERSON ), 0 ) AS TODAY_SALES,
    ( SELECT SUM( SALES_TOTAL ) FROM SALES WHERE MONTH ( SALES_DATE ) = '01' AND SALES_PERSON = sal.SALES_PERSON ) AS MONTH_TO_DATE_SALES 
FROM
    SALES AS sal 
GROUP BY
    SALES_PERSON
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do a do a sub query and over the result, make a Group by just in case you can have different sales for the same day

```
select sales_person,sum(today_sales),month_to_date
from
(SELECT a.sales_person,sum(a.sales_total) as today_sales,(select sum(sales_total)
                                         from sales b
                                         where year(b.sales_date)=year(a.sales_date) and month(b.sales_date)=month(a.sales_date)) as month_to_date
from sales as a
where a.sales_date=date(now())) c
group by sales_person,month_to_date
order by sales_person
```

Comment: only 1 record record showing. thanks anyway. I'll try playing around with this query first

Answer (score 0):

you could use a inner join with subquery for month  sales

```
select a.SALES_PERSON, a.SALES_TOTAL, t.month_total 
from SALES a 
inner join (
  select SALES_PERSON, month(SALES_DATE) month, year(SALES_DATE) year, sum(SALES_TOTAL) month_total
  from SALES 
  group by SALES_PERSON
) t ON t.SALES_PERSON = a.SALES_PERSON 
      AND t.month = month(curdate())
        AND t.year =  year(curdate())
WHERE a.SALES_DATE = curdate()
```

Comment: Your query returns result. but Josh sales is not showing. Thanks for this